# User can't connect to samba share on windows (others can)

Tags: windows-7, authentication, samba

I have setup Samba in a Debian machine so that existing users in the linux server can connect to their homes and different shares using Windows.

**user1**, **user2** and **user3** can connect without problems, but **user4** can't access any of the shares. **user4** can log in perfectly using SSH.

Samba outputs the following upon failed connection attempts (using **user4** credentials):

```
[2013/09/25 13:12:03.174008,  1] smbd/service.c:678(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_server_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Samba outputs the following upon successful connection attempts (using **user3** credentials at the same Windows machine):

```
[2013/09/25 13:13:04.564410,  1] smbd/service.c:1070(make_connection_snum)
  user-pc (::ffff:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) connect to service www initially as user user3 (uid=1001, gid=33) (pid 2046)
```

This is the output of vipw

```
user1:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:1002:1002:,,,:/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1003:,,,:/home/user3:/bin/bash
user4:x:1004:1004:,,,:/home/user4:/bin/bash
```

This is the output of /etc/groups

```
www-data:x:33:user1,user2,user3,user4
```

This is my smb.conf

```
    [global]
      workgroup = WORKGROUP
      server string = %h server
      dns proxy = no
      log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
      max log size = 1000
      syslog = 0
      panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
      security = user
      encrypt passwords = true
      passdb backend = tdbsam
      obey pam restrictions = yes
      unix password sync = yes
      passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
      passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
      pam password change = yes

   [homes]
      comment = Home Directories
      browseable = no
      read only = no
      create mask = 0775
      directory mask = 0775
      valid users = %S

   [vault]
      path=/mnt/vault/
      browseable=yes
      writeable=yes
      create mask = 0664
      directory mask = 0775
      valid users = user1 user2 user3 user4
      force group = www-data
```

I am not sure where else to look for differences between this users. **user4** was created recently and I don't know if I forgot something in the process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using tdbsam, so maybe you forgot to add user4 to samba's database

```sh
sudo smbpasswd -a user4
```

Comment: That was it, thank you very much. I had to delete the connection I had stablished with **user3** by using the following command in the windows machine: `net use \\server\share /delete`, before I could connect with **user4**